# How to have a background image properly fade in with CSS

Tags: html, css, animation, background, fade

How would I have an id, which contains a background image, to fade in with just CSS?

Here is what I have in my css file:

```
#header{
clear:both;
position:relative; 
z-index: 999; 
border-top: 3px solid #4C718F; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #C1D7E2; 
background: url(images/top-bg.png) repeat top right;
animation: fadein 3s;
-moz-animation: fadein 3s; /* Firefox */
-webkit-animation: fadein 3s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-animation: fadein 3s; /* Opera */

@keyframes fadein {
from {
    opacity:0;
}
to {
    opacity:3;
}
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein { /* Firefox */
from {
    opacity:0;
}
to {
    opacity:3;
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
from {
    opacity:0;
}
to {
    opacity:3;
}
}
@-o-keyframes fadein { /* Opera */
from {
    opacity:0;
}
to {
    opacity: 3;
}
}
}
```

The background image is not fading at all. I would appreciate any help, thank you.

EDIT-- Here is where I am calling the class in my HTML:

```
<div id="header-out">

    <div id="header">
        <div class="top-bar-wrap">
            <div id="top" class="col-full">
            <div id="logo" class="col-full">

            <?php if ($woo_options['woo_texttitle'] <> "true") : $logo = $woo_options['woo_logo']; ?>
                <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>">
                    <img id="ML" src="<?php if ($logo) echo $logo; else { bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/logo.png<?php } ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" />
                </a>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if( is_singular() && !is_front_page() ) : ?>
                <span class="site-title"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></span>
            <?php else : ?>
                <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
            <?php endif; ?>
                <span class="site-description"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></span>

            </div><!-- /#logo -->

            <?php if ( $woo_options['woo_ad_top'] == 'true' ) { ?>
            <div id="topad">
                <?php if ($woo_options['woo_ad_top_adsense'] <> "") { echo stripslashes($woo_options['woo_ad_top_adsense']);  } else { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $woo_options['woo_ad_top_url']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $woo_options['woo_ad_top_image']; ?>" width="468" height="60" alt="advert" /></a>
                <?php } ?>
            </div><!-- /#topad -->
            <?php } ?>

            <div id="navigation" class="asotv">
            <img src="wp-content/themes/biznizz/images/as-seen-on-tv.png">
                <?php
                if ( function_exists('has_nav_menu') && has_nav_menu('primary-menu') ) {
                    wp_nav_menu( array( 'depth' => 6, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'container' => 'ul', 'menu_id' => 'main-nav', 'menu_class' => 'nav fl', 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu' ) );
                } else {
                ?>
                <ul id="main-nav" class="nav fl">
                    <?php
                    if ( isset($woo_options['woo_custom_nav_menu']) AND $woo_options['woo_custom_nav_menu'] == 'true' ) {
                        if ( function_exists('woo_custom_navigation_output') )
                            woo_custom_navigation_output();
                    } else { ?>
                        <?php if ( is_page() ) $highlight = "page_item"; else $highlight = "page_item current_page_item"; ?>
                        <li class="<?php echo $highlight; ?>"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><?php _e('Home', 'woothemes') ?></a></li>
                        <?php
                            wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order&depth=6&title_li=&exclude=');
                    }
                    ?>
                </ul><!-- /#nav -->
                <?php } ?>
            </div><!-- /#navigation -->

            <div class="fix"></div>

        </div><!-- /#top -->
       </div>
        <?php //if ($woo_options['woo_slider'] == 'true' && is_home()) include ( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/featured.php' ); ?>
    </div><!-- /#header -->

</div><!-- /#header-out -->
```

Comment: is it neccessary to be the background-image?

Comment: It does not have to be a background image. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: yes, change that `background-image` to `content`. worked?

Comment: do you want this type of effect? http://www.mightymeta.co.uk/demos/fading-background-image/

Comment: I want exactly this type of effect when the page loads:
http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/VV2ek/

Comment: it could be a text as well?

Comment: No, I am trying to get the background image to fade in, but using the same effect as in that jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just want tell you that **modify your OPACITY** 3 to any other between 
**0.0 to 1.0** in CSS.

```
@keyframes fadein {
from {
    opacity:0;
}
to {
    opacity:1;
}
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein { /* Firefox */
from {
    opacity:0;
}
to {
    opacity:1;
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
from {
    opacity:0;
}
to {
    opacity:1;
}
}
@-o-keyframes fadein { /* Opera */
from {
    opacity:0;
}
to {
    opacity: 1;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-transform-background-image/).

This tells you about the transformations on background-image.

**Try** changing `background-image` to `content`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem. I simply had to edit the class as follows:

```
#header{
clear:both;
position:relative; 
z-index: 999; 
border-top: 3px solid #4C718F; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #C1D7E2; 
background: url(images/top-bg.png) repeat top right;
animation: fadein 3s;
-moz-animation: fadein 3s; /* Firefox */
-webkit-animation: fadein 3s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-animation: fadein 3s; /* Opera */

@keyframes fadein {
from {
opacity:0;
}
to {
opacity:1;
}
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein { /* Firefox */
from {
opacity:0;
}
to {
opacity:1;
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
from {
opacity:0;
}
to {
opacity:1;
```

Thank you all for your help,

Ralph.